# SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer returning false with Unity Remote?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-engine, accelerometer, android-sensors

when i try to understand status of device accelerometer support i use :
SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer

this value is false but im sure my device accelerometer works.the code is in below.

thanks a lot for your helps.

```
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;

    public class GyroTest : MonoBehaviour {
    public Text Xt;
    public Text Yt;
    public Text Zt;
    private float XX;
    private float YY;
    private float ZZ;
    private bool testvar;

    void Start()
    {
        testvar = SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer;
        Debug.Log("WXWXWXWXW:: " + testvar.ToString());

        if (SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer)
        {
            Debug.Log("Device Support Accelometer ");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Device Not Support Accelometer ");
        }
    }
    void Update () {

        XX = Input.acceleration.x;
        YY = Input.acceleration.y;
        ZZ = Input.acceleration.z;
        Xt.text = XX.ToString();
        Yt.text = YY.ToString();
        Zt.text = ZZ.ToString();

    }


}
```

Comment: `im sure my device accelerometer works` Please talk us through how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: @user3805054 Are you running this on the device device itself or through the Editor? What's your Unity and Android version?

Comment: @mjwills i have two reason for my diagnosis,one of them is that,i install an android sensor test on my device and and its check accelerometer completely and it works well  in addition application that needs accelerometer works correctly in my device.
and second reason is that at the end of code i print the result in my UI panel and it works well

Comment: @Programmer i test my code on my device with unity remote version 5. and my unity version is 2017.2.1f1 education.
in addition i test code on different android version and device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I test my code on my device with Unity Remote version 5

`SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer` does [not](https://feedback.unity3d.com/suggestions/systeminfo-dot-supportsaccelerometer-should-return-true-when-unity-remote-is-connected) work with Unity Remote. It will always return false when used via the Editor and Unity Remote. To use `SystemInfo.supportsAccelerometer`, build and run the app on the Android device itself. It should work on the the device when it is built. If it still return null on the Android device, file for a bug report because it shouldn't.

Comment: Great answer @Programmer.